# Android Accessibility: Click When Pointer Stops On Websites

Tags: accessibility

I have a disability that requires me to use the *Interaction And Dexterity: Click When Pointer Stops* accessibility setting on my Samsung Galaxy S9+. Unfortunately, this setting (in combination with the *Assistant Menu*) does not allow me to click on hyperlinks. While you can use *Assistant Menu: Cursor* to move a second pointer that does click links, it is virtually impossible to do this with any degree of accuracy.

Is there any way of using the same pointer for navigating the UI and navigating web pages? I have tried using the *Samsung Internet* and *Google Chrome* apps without success.

See: [Assistant Menu](https://www.samsung.com/uk/accessibility/mobile-assistant-menu/)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox for Android allows you to use *Accessibility: Interaction And Dexterity: Click When Pointer Stops* to click on hyperlinks. Having tested a number of browser apps, I have found the following browsers **do not** allow this:

- Samsung Internet
- Google Chrome
- Firefox Focus
- Opera / Opera Touch
- Microsoft Edge

I noticed that this accessibility feature does not work when the pointer is displayed as a hand.

Comment: Maybe there is some way of forcing the same pointer across the entire android UI?